# Why is ZnFe2O4 a normal spinel?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, crystal-structure, transition-metals, solid-state-chemistry

Considering that $\ce{Zn^2+}$ is $\mathrm{d}^{10}$, $\ce{Fe^3+}$ is $\mathrm{d^5}$, and $\ce{O^2-}$ is a weak field ligand, the CFSE values of both the normal and inverse spinel structures should be $0$.

Why is it then that the normal spinel, with $\ce{Zn^2+}$ in tetrahedral holes and $\ce{Fe^3+}$ in octahedral holes, is formed?

Answer (score 5):

The reason stated in the literature is fairly straightforward. However, actually tracking down the original source is harder than it looks.

Going back to [Phys. Rev. B22, 115 (1980)](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.22.115) one finds in the opening paragraph the statement

> Mixed Zn ferrites of the type Zn$_{x}$M$_{3-x}$O$_{4}$ where M
>   is a magnetic ion have been the subject of numerous
>   investigations in the past, especially with regard to
>   their magnetic properties.$^{1}$ The metallic ions occupy
>   the tetrahedral A or octahedral B sites in the spinel
>   crystal structure. The Zn ions preferentially occupy
>   the A sites because of their tendency to form covalent
>   bonds involving sp' orbitals.

Reference number 1, on the first sentence, is a book [J. Smit and H.P.J. Wihn, Ferrites (Wiley, New York, 1959)]. The statement on $sp3$ bonding is not backed up by a reference. I can only assume that it was considered common knowledge in the spinel community in 1980.